# Loop through a list of Observables and assign the result of each Obsservable to an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and RxJS, but I have a list of social posts and for each social post I need to execute a call to the server to get users, who reacted on the current social post. Here is a picture of what's happening (the grey arrows are requests):
[image]

Basically, I've created a service which returns the users for a specific post. The code which I implented so far:

The service function:

```
getUsersForSocialPost(socialPostId: number, count: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.apollo
      .query({
      query: GET_USERS_CREATED_REACTION_ON_SOCIAL_POST,
      variables: {
        socialPostId,
        take: count
      }, fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
    }).pipe(take(1), catchError(err => throwError({message: err.networkError.error.errors[0]})));
  }
```

The function inside my component:

```
for (const post of this.pagedSocialPosts) {
      const id = post.id;
      const viewCounter = post.reactionGists.find((item => item.type === 'VIEW')).count;
      const socialPostStats = {socialPost: post.value, views: viewCounter, users: []};

      /!* Make a call to retrieve all users from the database *!/
      observables.push(this.socialPostService.getUsersForSocialPost(+id, +viewCounter)
        .subscribe((result): any => {
          const socialPostReactionGists: SocialPostReactionGist[] = result.data.socialPostById.reactionGists;
          const users: User[] = [...socialPostReactionGists.find((item => item.type === 'VIEW')).PagedUsers.items];
          if (users.length > 0) {
            users.forEach((user) => socialPostStats.users.push(user.email));
          }
          socialPostsStats.push(socialPostStats);
        }, error => {
          this.toastService.error(
            `${error.message.message}`,
            'Can\'t fetch users:',
            {disableTimeOut: true});
        }));
    }
    console.log('Social Posts Stats: ', {location: this.location.displayName, socialPostsStats});
```

Due to the fact that the code is asynchronous, the `console.log` prints empty array.
I read in some other posts, that for such purpose can be used the `forkJoin` operator and I tried it as well - it works, however I need to iterate one more time through the result, so I can create the final object. Is there an alternative or better approach, so I can save some iterations?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use ***combineLatest*** from RxJs.
Visit https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest for more details

Sample code:

```
combineLatest(ARRAY_OF_OBSERVABLES)
.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
.subscribe((ARRAY_OF_RESPONSES) => {
    // Do anything with ARRAY_OF_RESPONSES
})
```

ARRAY_OF_OBSERVABLES is Array of observables/requests
ARRAY_OF_RESPONSES is Array of responses from observables/requests